# Accessing previous index's item from within a knockout foreach loop?

Tags: knockout.js

I have a chat application that lists messages - if the current message and previous message were posted by the same user, I'd like to not show the username on the current message.

To get started with this, I'm trying to navigate out of the `foreach` to access the array by relative index.  It seems like I can't even access an item via direct index though:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach:array1">
    <li data-bind="text:$parent.array1()[0]">Should be John, works</li>
    <li data-bind="text:$parent.array1()[$index]">Should be the same as $data, but throws error</li>
</ul>
```

Eventually, I'd like to do the following:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach:array1">
    <li data-bind="text:$parent.array1()[$index - 1]">Happens after index 0 only</li>
</ul>
```

Fiddle demonstrating the first issue:   http://jsfiddle.net/xveEP/148/

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you check Knockout changelog the `$index` was implemented in version 2.1.0: http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2012/05/09/knockout-2-1-0-released/ so changing version in jsfiddle solves problem no 1 partially. You will not see an error anymore.

Now you will have to bind `$index` properly. According to documentation it is an observable so to use it in expression you need to return its value: `data-bind="text:$parent.array1()[$index()]"`. Knockout text binding documentation Note 1: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/text-binding.html

This gives us working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xveEP/150/

And when you put the same solution (change version and use `$index()` in expression) to the second problem you can do what you wanted: http://jsfiddle.net/xveEP/151/

Comment: The last fiddle does not appear to work. I see `array 1
John
Joe` as output

Comment: That's exactly what you are supposed to see. For each array element previous is printed. array1[0-1] is undefined so only two are visible. Check fiddle with indexes: http://jsfiddle.net/xveEP/203/

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want for your first problem. Instead of `$index`, use `ko.utils.arrayIndexOf($parent.array1, $data)`. Updated fiddle is here http://jsfiddle.net/rwisch45/xveEP/149/

Comment: Thanks.  I'd prefer not to traverse the whole array for each item if possible... this solution pushes rendering to n^2 if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

Since this wasn't actually solved, here is a solution that works:

You can use $index() - 1 to point to the previous item, then perform whatever logic you need on it. Referencing array1[$index() - 1].property will throw an error on the first item because array1[-1] does not exist, so you have to do it conditionally as in:

```
data-bind="text: (array1[$index()-1]) ? array1[$index()-1].property : ''"
```

complete example: http://jsfiddle.net/DougLeary/p6xhd3uk/